# How to detect that any browser supports which codec in WebRTC?

Tags: firefox, video, twilio, webrtc, codec

I am using twilio-video.js 1.6.0, video call works in chrome. but in firefox 62 video is not coming during video call. I want to check which codecs are supported by current firefox browser? how can I detect which codecs are supported in any browser?

Answer (score 0):

The supported codecs are available in the SDP offer or answer (depends on whether the local peer is the caller or callee, respectively).